# ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pyorc

Tags: python

I have installed pyorc using:
python -m pip install pyorc

Nevertheless I constatly have the same error when I try to import pyorc

---

IPython 7.19.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
**strong text**
import pyorc
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
import pyorc
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyorc_*init*_.py", line 14, in 
from .reader import Column, Reader, Stripe
File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyorc\reader.py", line 4, in 
from pyorc._pyorc import reader, stripe
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pyorc: Impossível localizar o módulo especificado.

---

These are my packages:

[Packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPodp.png)